# Como faço pra acrescentar manualmente uma observação num objeto "ts" em R?

Tags: r, funções

Estou importando a série histórica do IGP-M, mas lá no Sistema Gerenciador de séries temporais ainda não tem o dado de dezembro (divulgado hoje, 29/12). Estou com o seguinte:

```
igpm <- BETSget(189,from = '2000-01-01') %>%
dplyr::select(value) %>%
ts(start = c(2000,01),freq=12) %>%
```

Depois desse último "pipe" quero inserir um comando para acrescentar manualmente o dado de dezembro.

Answer (score -2):

Em vez de usar uma outra função ali no "pipe", você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
y=.87
igpm=ts(rbind(igpm,y),start=c(2000,01),freq=12)
```